# Inhetirance java, how can I do this?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I need to ask u some help about some problem that I have.

I need to create a superclass called "Cuadrilatero" and a sub class called "Paralelogramo".

Paralelogramo is going to extend Cuadrilatero. Cuadrilatero have 4 points with coords for X and Y that I need to inherit to the subclass Paralelogramo.

Here's the code.

```
public class Cuadrilatero {

private double P1;
private double P2;
private double P3;
private double P4;

private double x1,x2,x3,x4,y1,y2,y3,y4;


public Cuadrilatero() {
}

public Cuadrilatero(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double x3, double y3, double x4, double y4){
    setP1(x1, y1);
    setP2(x2, y2);
    setP3(x3, y3);
    setP4(x4, y4);
}

//creación de los puntos

public void setP1(double x1, double y1){
    this.x1=x1;
    this.y1=y1;
}

public double getP1(){
    return P1;
}


public void setP2(double x2, double y2){
    this.x2=x2;
    this.y2=y2;
} 

public double getP2(){
    return P2;
}

public void setP3(double x3, double y3){
    this.x3=x3;
    this.y3=y3;
}

public double getP3(){
    return P3;
}


public void setP4(double x4, double y4){
    this.x4=x4;
    this.y4=y4;
}

public double getP4(){
    return P4;
}

}
```

and the Paralelogramo class

```
class Paralelogramo extends Cuadrilatero{

private double altura;
private double base;

public Paralelogramo(){
}

public Paralelogramo(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double x3, double y3, double x4, double y4){
 super(P1,P2,P3,P4);
 }

public Paralelogramo(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double x3, double y3, double x4, double y4,double altura, double base){
    setAltura(altura);
    setBase(base);
}

public void setAltura(double altura){
    this.altura=altura;

}

public double getAltura(){
    altura=y2-y1;
    return altura;
}

public void setBase(double base){
    this.base=base;
}

public double getBase(){
    base=x4-x1;
    return base;
}

public double getArea(){
    double area;

    area= getBase() * getAltura();

    return area;

}

public String toString(){
    return "El area del [Paralelogramo] es: " + getArea() + " cuadrados";
    }
}
```

When I compile Cuadrilatero theres not a problem but when I compile Cuadrilatero showns an error with the variable P1,P2,P3,P4 and the X and Y. "Has private Access"

How Can I solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Java, difference between package private, public, protected, and private](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-difference-between-package-private-public-protected-and-private)

Comment: @shinjw that's not the problem here

Comment: What are `P1`, `P2`, etc.?  I think you mean them to be "points", with two coordinates, but you've declared them to be one `double`.  You can't store two real values in one double.  So what is `getP1` supposed to return?  It can't return a point if you've declared that it returns just one `double`.

Comment: Even once you get things to compile, you will have other problems. (1) What prevents the caller from constructing a parallelogram with four points that aren't really a parallelogram?  (2) Why would you have a constructor that takes all four points *and* the height and base?  The height and base are computable from the points, so this allows a caller to create a parallelogram with a height and base that contradict the points.  (3) For a similar reason, why do you allow them to set the height?  (4) Since you change `altura` every time `getAltura` is called, there's no point to `setAltura()`.

Answer (score 1):

First mistakes you have here:

```
public Paralelogramo(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double x3, double y3, double x4, double y4){
 super(P1,P2,P3,P4);
 }
```

You should change above to this:

```
public Paralelogramo(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double x3, double y3, double x4, double y4){
 super(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4);

}

public Paralelogramo(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double x3, double y3, double x4, double y4,double altura, double base){
 super(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4);
    setAltura(altura);
    setBase(base);
}
```

But there are still other problems. Your variable `P1 or P2` has type double so when you say

```
`public double getP1(){
    return P1;
}`
```

It will return 0.

Possible fix: Create a new class `Point which takes an x and y then work further with the instances of that Point class.

Answer (score 0):

In your question, I assume you meant that you are getting errors when compiling the *Paralelogramo* class. One of the constructors of that class:

```js
public Paralelogramo(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double x3, double y3, double x4, double y4) {
  super(P1, P2, P3, P4);
}
```

This line is using variables that are available in the super class, but they have the private modifier and hence it won't work. You need to use the *protected* access modifier to allow access by sub-classes.

Answer (score 0):

As still exposed by previous answers the problem that cause the error is in the call of the base class costructor.
In the first definition of `Paralelogramo` costructor

```
 public Paralelogramo(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double x3, double y3, double x4, double y4){
 super(P1,P2,P3,P4);
 }
```

the problem is in the number of parameters: `super` (i.e the costructor of Quadrilatero), as you defined it, needs 8 parameters but when you call it you provide only 4 parameters.
The second definition of `Paralogramo` costructor

```
public Paralelogramo(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double x3, double y3, double x4, double y4,double altura, double base){
        //here there is a hidden call to super() i.e.
        //in this case Quadrilatero()
        setAltura(altura);
        setBase(base);
    }
```

calls the base class costructor without parameters but it does **nothing** when instead it should be initialize the attributes to some values.
But in my opinion the error is in the initial concept: if `Quad` is a base class extended by a subclass `Parallelogram`, the attributes in common beetween `Quad` and `Parallogram` should be `protected` to make these accessible to subclass, and not `private` that make these accessible only from `Quad` itself.